# How to browse Samba network shares from PC Settings in Windows 8.1

Tags: debian, windows-8.1, network-shares, samba, modern-ui

For some time I have kept a lot of my files stored on a home server running Debian Linux with Samba. I have several shares connected as network drives and, using the desktop interface under Windows 8.1 have no problem accessing the files.

I recent tried browsing for a new Lock Screen image from PC Settings, but found that, while the drives are visible, the application reports "There are no files or folders in this view.".

How do I enable access to my network shares from Wiindows 8l.1 Modern (Metro) Apps such as the PC Settings tool?

To confirm, I have no problem browsing or copying from the desktop file explorer or other desktop applications.